# react native show current time and update the seconds in real-time

Tags: reactjs, timer, react-native, clock

I want to show the current time(MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss) in react native app like a clock, and get update every seconds, I tried using new Date() and set it in state, but the time don't update unless I refresh the page.
I also tried using setInterval function in render(), it do got update but it's expensive for CPU. is there a good method to realise the function?

```
state = {
    curTime: null,
}
render(){
    setInterval(function(){this.setState({curTime: new  Date().toLocaleString()});}.bind(this), 1000);
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={headerStyle.marginBottom15}>Date: {this.state.curTime}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just move `setInterval` into componentDidMount function.

Like this :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        curTime : new Date().toLocaleString()
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
```

This will change state and update every 1s.

Comment: Thanks, I just got the answer, componentWillMount(){
        setInterval(function(){
            this.setState({
                curTime: new Date().toLocaleString()
            })
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 21):

in react hooks, it can be done like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const [dt, setDt] = useState(new Date().toLocaleString());

useEffect(() => {
    let secTimer = setInterval( () => {
      setDt(new Date().toLocaleString())
    },1000)

    return () => clearInterval(secTimer);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 15):

This method works fine and displays **MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss** format

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          time: new Date().toLocaleString()
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.intervalID = setInterval(
          () => this.tick(),
          1000
        );
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      }
      tick() {
        this.setState({
          time: new Date().toLocaleString()
        });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <p className="App-clock">
            The time is {this.state.time}.
          </p>
        );
      }
    }
```

original link : https://openclassrooms.com/courses/build-web-apps-with-reactjs/build-a-ticking-clock-component

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer. The code below also works.

```
componentWillMount(){
    setInterval(function(){
        this.setState({
            curTime: new Date().toLocaleString()
        })
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: But if I don't .bind(this), I got this error: this.setState is not a function.

Comment: Yes, I have saw your example, it's a little different from mine, you pass a es6 arrow function as first param in setInterval. here is my full code:

Comment: Sorry, not able to past my full code here for characters length limit here.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to prefer using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, indeed, the browser may be overhelmed by heavy processing and in that case you would probably prefer updating the clock less often instead of queuing several updates of the state.

With `setTimeout` it is also a bit easier to leverage the Page Visibility API to completely stop the clock when the page is hidden (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

```
export default class MyClock {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentTime: Date.now(),
    }; 
  }

  updateCurrentTime() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      currentTime: Date.now(),
    }));
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.updateCurrentTime.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.updateCurrentTime();
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
      if(document.hidden) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
      } else {
        this.updateCurrentTime();
      }
    }, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full Code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class KenTest extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){ 

    setInterval(() => (

      this.setState(
        { curTime : new Date().toLocaleString()}

      )
    ), 1000);
  }


state = {curTime:new Date().toLocaleString()};


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
  <Text>{'\n'}{'\n'}{'\n'}The time is: {this.state.curTime}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using hooks and moment-js:

```
setInterval(() => {
  var date = moment().utcOffset("-03:00").format(" hh:mm:ss a");
  setCurrentDate(date);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: This should only be a comment to Ilana Hakim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998067/1280867). It adds nothing new with regard to how the original question can be solved via hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().toLocaleString());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{time}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```