# Getting the application or the OS's running time in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to get the elapsed running time of an application in React Native?

If possible to get some form of ticks which is not related to the device's time & date.

Pseudo code:

```
const ticks = Application.getTicks();
console.log(ticks);
```

While changing the device's date & time will not affect the returned ticks.

Comment: Why not just keep track of the current`dateTIme` on start up? Then when you want to check subtract the current `datetime` to the one on start up?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense We're trying to prevent users from tampering with the date and time of the device to effect their check in time while the device is offline

Comment: Getting the current `dateTime` in `JavaScript` does not get the device `dateTime` using `new Date()` does not get the device time. Am I just not understanding you correctly?

Comment: In React Native it does get the device time as far as I know. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294576/react-native-show-current-time-and-update-the-seconds-in-real-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer on the [following Gist](https://gist.github.com/stecman/71a5cead43eeef8fbc4c54eb97fe5ebd).

To utilize it, I've built [a simple module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-relative-time) that returns the number of seconds since the OS was started.

Here is the [Github repository](https://github.com/dht/react-native-relative-time).

The usage is as following:

```
import RelativeTime from 'react-native-relative-time';
```

and:

```
RelativeTime.getRelativeTime()
    .then(ticks => console.log(ticks);
```

It returns the number of seconds since the OS started:

- Restarting the Android simulator resets the value returned **(as expected)**
- Restaring the iOS simulator seems to keep the value. Probably means the value which is returned is the Mac's uptime.
- Changing the device's time does not change the value returned **(as expected)**

[image: iOS]

[image: Android]

Comment: since in iOS you use time(&now) to calculate the elapsed time, doesn't that compromise the uptime? if a user changes time settings it will return a false value